# Import Scenario for Update

Tags: import, acumatica, scenarios

I want to create an import scenario to update some fields within the Contact table, I do not want to have duplicated records, how can I indicate what contact number to update?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ContactID field

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit more?